# Running ssd files on Beebem emulator

Tags: acorn

I have downloaded L Mathemagical Adventure and I am running it on Beebem emulator. I selected the ssd file with load disk, but it came up with the error message that the file was read only. It talked about removing the 'write protect' label from the edge of the disk, so I assume it is referring to a physical copy.

---

How do I allow Beebem to run this ssd file and make the ssd file editable??

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: @user3840170 As I remember, emulators are considered modern software and, thus, not retrocomputing by the definition of this SE. If it were a question that also applied equally to running it on vintage hardware, then it'd be a different story.

Comment: Compare <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/15334>, however.

Comment: @user3840170 Yes, but that example is a question that applies equally to emulated or actual hardware. "How do I remove the emulated write protect label?" does not apply equally well to a real, physical write-protect label on vintage hardware.

Comment: I think this IS on-topic. The emulator is for a BBC Microcomputer, undisputedly within scope for Retrocomputing, and the question is not about the engineering of the emulator itself but the use of it in order to run retrosoftware. Given that we accept questions about post-2000 PCs as on-topic, I think the boundaries are sufficiently blurred that this question is OK. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru You said it, it's a question how to use a modern emulator, still being developed. The question belongs to emulator support site, but frankly, this is a case of not bothering to read the manual for the emulator.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru The question provides information for  a simple first test or being on topic: _"Does the Beep have SSD files?"_. If the answer is no, then it's off topic, as it is most likely about the modern emulator, its modern environment and interactions inbetween.